# Drawing exponential curve without breaks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using scipy for non-linear regression optimalization (least_square method). I am drawing the result to the graph utilizing matplotlib and PyQt5. The problem is that the final graph should be exponential and there should not be any breaks like on this picture [my current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZ0Cp.jpg). How can I draw it like exponential curve like this without any breaks? [Exponential curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1d9j.png)

```
            self.figure = Figure()
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
            layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.content_plot)
            layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
            layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

            self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
            result = self.results[id]
            self.fillResultTable(result)
            self.setLabelsForResult(result)
    
            x = np.asarray(result.profitList)
            y = np.asarray(result.utilityList)
            resList = result.resList // resList contains found points for new curve which should be exponential 
            self.ax.plot(x, y, "o", label="Initial points")
            self.ax.legend(loc='lower right')
            self.ax.plot(x, resList, label='Final utility function')
            self.ax.legend(loc='lower right')

    class LeastSquaresOptimalization:
        def __init__(self, profitList, utilityList):
            self.profitList = np.asarray(profitList) // list of profits
            self.utilityList = np.asanyarray(utilityList) // list of corresponding utilities 
    
        def function(self, params, x):
            a = params[0]
            b = params[1]
            c = params[2]
    
            return a * np.exp(-x/b) + c
        
        def residual(self, params, x, y):
            return (y - self.function(params, x))**2
        
        def startOptimalization(self, a_start, b_start, c_start):
            x0 = np.array([a_start, b_start, c_start])
            bnds = ([-np.inf, 0.00000001, -np.inf], [-0.00000001, np.inf, np.inf])
            result = least_squares(self.residual, x0, args=(self.profitList, self.utilityList), bounds=bnds)
            SSE = self.countSSE(result)
            pointList = self.countPoints(result)
            return result, SSE, pointList
       
        def countPoints(self, result): // this method is used for resList which contains found points
            res = self.function(result.x, self.profitList)
            return res
```

Comment: You have a continuous function, you're just not plotting enough points.  You're only using x values that match your data points.  Just use `arange` to generate 200 evenly-spaced points along your x axis, and you'll get a smooth curve.  I would show you code, but I don't see where you generate `resList`.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks. I added code which explains how resList is obtained. Would you mind showing me code how to do it please? I am not really sure I understand how to do it :/

Comment: In `countPoints`, if you pass `np.arange(200)` instead of `self.profitList`, you'll generate a smoother curve.  That's not quite enough, because you'll need to pass that `arange` vector to `self.ax.plot` instead of `x`.  I can't see how to fit that in.  Maybe you should call `countPoints` during the plotting process, so you control both the x and y values.

Comment: thank you very much! :) So basically when I find the parameters (a, b, c) of the function (with regression) I can generate with those parameters and function more values than my initial for example 7 values which I had in profitList and it is still correct solution, right? :)

Comment: Right.  Once you have the parameters, you can generate a y for any arbitrary x.  That's the whole point of doing a regression like this.